# External Monitor Sound Volume Slider AND auto switching

Tags: macos, display, audio, sound-volume, speakers

I just switched from an iMac to a MacBook 14 inch. I've swapped out my iMac with a Samsung HDMI monitor with a speaker, and it plays sound correctly. However, the volume slider is disabled. I could fix this with [Proxy Audio device](https://github.com/briankendall/proxy-audio-device), as it routed the sound through a volume-changing-compatible device to the monitor. However, when I unplugged my MacBook to go places, I had to change my sound output back to the internal speakers because the Samsung monitor was no longer attached. Then I tried creating a multi-output device with both the monitor and built-in speakers, but the monitor had enough lag that it was nearly impossible to listen to anything with the monitor making a louder echo of the MacBook (which I keep in a vented cabinet with a dock).

So this is my request - can I have my Mac switch to my monitor speakers, with full volume control, when I plug in my monitor, then switch back to the internal speakers when I unplug the monitor? Finally, if this cannot be done for free, I'll just switch the output myself every time I leave or consider using the macbook's internal speakers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the monitor has a 3.5mm audio jack, you could always go old school and use an audio cable direct.

Comment: My monitor does not have an audio jack, and I don't have any external speakers lying around. However, I do have an old-school way, which would be to just increase the volume on my MacBook and use its speakers, but I would like to use this after exhausting software solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I positioned the macbook below my monitor for cooling reasons, and now the speakers are loud enough so I dont need external speakers.